# Copy a SQL Server 2008 database verbatim

Tags: database, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to copy my entire SQL Server 2008 database including the schema and all data *verbatim* from one computer to another.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the database from the original server and then import it into the new one.

To export right click over the name then **Tasks > Backup...**. If you make sure you select the "Backup type" as **Full** and "Backup component" as **Database** this should copy everything.

To import right click again then **Tasks > Restore > Database...**.

Comment: This is the best way to do it.  Isn't backup/restore different than export/import?

Comment: @Bratch - technically, but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

See this MS knowledgebase article: [How to move databases between computers that are running SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314546)

Answer (score 0):

If you can take it offline for a while, it is quicker to detach it, copy the mdf and ldf files, and then just re-attach it.

Comment: Will all users and permissions and such be included?

Comment: @howdy: Yes, but you will need to re-create the server logins and associated with the database users (the logins exist at the server level, not the database).

Comment: Those can be scripted seperately

Answer (score 0):

This question on Stackoverflow might be of some use to you. [How can I export data from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787345/how-can-i-export-data-from-sql-server/1787373#1787373).

Hope this helps some.